# Why is my NPM audit giving me "angular <=1.7.9 Severity: high" when this dependency isn't even included?

Tags: angular, npm

For some weird reason my project was giving me the following warning when running `npm audit`:

```
angular  <=1.7.9
Severity: high
Cross-Site Scripting in angular - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-r5fx-8r73-v86c
Prototype Pollution in angular - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-89mq-4x47-5v83
Cross-Site Scripting via JSONP - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-28hp-fgcr-2r4h
XSS via JQLite DOM manipulation functions in AngularJS - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-5cp4-xmrw-59wf
```

Even though when listing all of the project packages, there was no trace of any Angular dependencies less than version 1.7.9 (I'm using Angular 13.3.3).

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that the containing folder was called `angular` (I'm keeping the different components of the application in respective folders), and for some fun reason it causes this issue. I wasted quite a bit of time trying to figure this one out.

Don't name your Angular project folder "angular"...

Comment: Lol, that's good advice, and a very strange issue!